# ionic 5 - Create tabs in existing project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to add tabs to an existing project in ionic 5.

Following the documentation (https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/tabs) I placed the following code:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab [root]="tabs1"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tabs2"></ion-tab>
  </ion-tabs>
</ion-content>
```

Inside the *.page.ts* file I made sure *tabs1* and *tabs2* were Pages:

```
import {PersonPage} from '../person/person.page'

   ....
  tabs1 = PersonPage;
  tabs2 = PersonPage;
```

But I keep getting the error:

> Can't bind to 'root' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-tab'

Can someone tell why is there no property root in the component since it says so in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using v3 documentation (https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/components/#tabs) rather than the latest (https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/tabs).

Answer (score 0):

Like @below43 mention in the comments you are using v3 docs. An example of the new version in your case would look like this,

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab tab="tab1">
    <ion-header translucent>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Person 1</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content fullscreen class="ion-padding">
      <app-person-page [data]="person1Data"></app-person-page>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab tab="tab2">
    <ion-header translucent>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Person 2</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content fullscreen class="ion-padding">
      <app-person-page [data]="person2Data"></app-person-page>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Where `app-person-page` is the selector of `PersonPage` component, that takes as input `data` the person information (just to make it more illustrative).